# Sistema de permissões

Tags: php

Tenho um cadastro de usuários e um campo da tabela de usuários onde será armazenado as permissões para editar arquivos(ex. 1-editar, 2-excluir) e será armazenado em MySQL.

Alguém poderia ajudar pois não sei como poderia fazer esse controle com PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugero um modelo mais simples e rápido para exercer o objetivo.
Supomos que temos uma tabela assim:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
   id int unsigned not null AUTO_INCREMENT, /* numero de usuário */
   username varchar(30), /* nome de usuário */
   ...
   perm tinyint, /* as permissões */
   PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

O código para usar este modelo será mais ou menos este (não possui do processo da autorização e iniciação da sessão):

```
<?php

// podemos definir as permissoes como constantes
define('READ', 0);
define('WRITE', 1);
define('DELETE', 2);

// usando comandos preparados, a inserção de dados será mais segura
$db = new mysqli("host","login","password","database");
$s = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios where username=?");
$s->bind_param('s', $_POST['usuario']);
$s->execute();
$s->bind_result($id,$usuario,$perm);
$s->fetch();

// assim podemos verificar simplesmente se o usuario tem a permissão para preceder com a operação
if(pode_editar($perm))
        echo "USUARIO $usuario PODE EDITAR";

// as funções para verificação de permissões
// cada função vai retornar true ou false dependente da variável dada
function pode_ler($perm) {
return ($perm >= READ ? true : false);
}
function pode_editar($perm) {
return ($perm <= WRITE ? true : false);
}
function pode_eliminar($perm) {
return ($perm == DELETE && $perm <= DELETE ? true : false);
}
```

Comment: Boa resposta, mas acho que as condições não estão direitas. Não seria `$perm >= WRITE` na `pode_editar` e somente `$perm == DELETE` na `pode_eliminar`?

Comment: Podia ser $perm == DELETE no caso o usuário é limitado SÓ para eliminar, mas no caso para ele poder também ler e editar é preciso aquilo que eu fiz. Se o write for >= 1 isto vai significar "mais ou igual", assim o utilizador vai conseguir eliminar também, mas sem permissão da leitura.

Comment: Tim não estou a perceber o teu raciocínio, se tens uma função que verifica se pode eliminar não deveria verificar apenas se pode eliminar?

Comment: Normalmente nos casos da edição dos artigos nos CMS a permissão é atribuida deste modo acrescentável, quando utilizador vai conseguir ler se tem a permissão de editar ou eliminar. Mas podia ser como você disse também, neste caso vai ser preciso verificar multiplas funcões, tal como `if(pode_ler($perm) && pode_editar($perm))`. O meu raciocínio supõe a utilização de uma função só.

Comment: Ok, nesse exemplo o usuário poderá por exemplo Ler e Escrever com a permissão 1, e com a permissão 2 poderá Ler, Escrever e Deletar ? Seria esse o propósito, e no banco armazenaria apenas o 0,1 ou 2.

Comment: Sim, é exatamente essa lógica.

Comment: Obviamente pode optar por outra lógica tendo cada função a verificar apenas o determinado, como o Jorge sugeriu anteriormente. Neste caso vai ter de colocar 3 colunas na tabela como 3 permissões separadas e mudar as operações de comparação das funções para `$perm == DELETE`, `$perm == WRITE` e `$perm == READ`.

Comment: Teria como dar uma olhada nesse link e ver se seria +/- assim? https://github.com/tiagobuchanelli/PHP-e-MySQL/blob/master/PERMISS%C3%95ES%20PHP.php